# How to copy Form from development to prod?

Tags: orbeon

Is there any guideline to copy the Form from Development Server to Production Server e.g. export/import Form Configuration? It would be duplicate effort to create the form manually again in Production, especially if the form required to add images.

Thanks.

Comment: er.... http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/packaging-and-deployment

Comment: I don't see this related to my questions.

Comment: No offense, but avernet was giving the right answer I'm looking for.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I gave you. Publishing the forms from dev to production. Deployment of your forms from dev to production. Copying your forms from dev to production. It doesn't matter what language you use, all of that means the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish forms from a dev to a production server, or more generally from one environment to another, using the Form Runner Home Page, accessed in "admin mode". You can learn more about this in the [Remote server operations](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/feature/home-page.html#remote-server-operations) section of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks avernet! Great that orbeon has support the deployment features to Production.

Comment: @PooCb You're welcome, and of course just let us know you have any trouble deploying forms to other servers from the Form Runner home page.